# How to generate csrf token for API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing some API for my mobile app, and I want to add some action to render CSRF token in JSON. I know that there is helper csrf_meta_tags for HTML views, but how can I do it in controller? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`form_authenticity_token`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html#method-i-form_authenticity_token) in the controller. It uses `session[:_csrf_token]` as suggested by @user123, and also initialize it if it has not been done yet (see [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c60be72c5243c21303b067c9c5cc398111cf48c8/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L193-L195)).

Answer (score 2):

use the value in

```
session[:_csrf_token]
```